# Change background color on rows, but not row headers

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to change the background color of a table's rows using CSS, but I do not want to change a table heading's background.  However, by default, a TH is wrapped in a TR, so the TR rule is pushed to my TH.

Here's a jsfiddle to test with, if it helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/Bcayc/

Comment: The fiddle has no th? th:hover {background:#fff} not good enough?

Comment: that wouldn't work with the tr:hover rule

Comment: Sorry - I was trying several things with the fiddle and posted a version without a th rule.  Just meant to use it as a starting point, anyway, since it wasn't working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to differenciate your header rows from the data rows. This way you can target only the desired ones:

```
table tbody td:hover{
    background: #f00;
}

table tbody tr:hover{
    background: #00f;
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Qk3DB/)**

Along with the following markup:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1</td>
            <td>Col 2</td>
            <td>Col 3</td>
            <td>Col 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the best method has been posted using thead and tbody.

Alternatively, as a concept, you could add a class to the header-tr, and define a static background color, place after the hover condition in the .css

```
table td:hover{
    background: #f00;
}

table td:hover{
    background: #00f;
}

table .nohover:hover{
    background: #fff;   
}

<table>
    <tr class="nohover">
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
        <td>Col 4</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
        <td>Col 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

​

Answer (score 1):

OR every second row + hover

```
tbody tr:nth-child(2n), tbody tr:hover{
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
```